# Converting date to values

Tags: excel, date, formatting, vba

I have a macro that copies volumes of data, some of the the values of which are dates. I have managed to get the data to show as required in the cell (ddmmyyyy) however, when copying the data to another destination, it copies as either the numerical value (E.g: 42005), or copies as the date (dd/mm/yyyy).

I need the cells to copy the physical numbers that can be seen in the cell (E.g: 01012015) and paste them into the new destination. My current coding uses:
`wsTarget.Range("X" & lTargetRow).Value = wsSource.Range("X1").value` system to move the data. I have tried using Value and Value2 with no success, and text causes my code to error.

I have done quite a bit of googling and found nothing. The only way I can get it to change is by physically formatting the cells as above, however I could really do with the date as represented by the the example above. Can anyone help?

Comment: Date is a format, you will need to copy and paste the formats. In this one instance I would recommend using copy paste instead of assigning values.

Comment: The file that the data is copied into (.CSV) cannot contain such formats and the date has to be in a purely numerical format. This was my issue. I have just tried using the `.copy` and `pastespecial` to no avail, using `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` and a few different other variations, but the physical cell formatting follows into the .CSV file.

Comment: Then change the `.value` to `.text`

Comment: @Scott Cranar You are quite right good sir. I had tried this before and got the "Run-time error '424': Object Required", however upon your request I realized I was trying to run `wsTarget.Range("X" & lTargetRow).text =wsSource.Range("X1").value2` instead of `wsTarget.Range("X" & lTargetRow).Value2 =wsSource.Range("X1").Text`. Thank you for this nudge in the right direction!